Windows 11 stops detecting HDMI AV receiver as sound device until reboot
My Windows 11 PC uses an AV receiver (Sony STR-DN1030) as its sound output device. It's connected via the HDMI port on the Nvidia display adapter. This has been working fine, but in the last week it has stopped detecting the receiver as a sound device, and will only detect it again if I reboot.
My hardware specs are:

Aorus B450 AORUS ELITE
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER 6GB Twin Fan Graphics Card
32GB RAM.

The first time this happened it was after I had changed the input source on the receiver to "Network" (to use the receiver as a DLNA player briefly). The next time it happened after I connected a pair of bluetooth earphones to the PC, to test them as an alternative sound device.
Any idea why the HDMI audio device is being "forgotten", and how I can stop it happening?
